# Handle more than 5000 connections without PGBouncer in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

We are using, PostgreSQL Version 14.
Our PC configuration at production

- Windows 2016 Server
- 32 GB RAM
- 8 TB Hard disk
- 8 Core CPU

In my PostgreSQL.conf file

- Shared_buffer 8 GB
- Work_MEM 1 GB
- Maintenance_work_mem 1 GB
- Max_Connections 1000

I wish to handle 5000 connection at a time. Somebody suggest me to go with PGBouncer.

But we initially starts with PostgreSQL without PGBouncer.

I need to know, is my configuration is OK with the 5000 connection or we need to increase RAM or any other...
This is our first, PostgreSQL implementation. So Please suggest me to start with PostgreSQL with out PGBouncer.

Thank you

Note:
In SQL if we set -1, it will handle more number of connections. Like this is there any configuration is available in PostgreSQL

Comment: With such a low-end server and only 8 CPUs 1000 connections are already quite unrealistic.  Although Postgres 14 introduced some optimizations regarding connection handling, 5000 are probably still a stretch. If you can't use pgBouncer, then maybe your application can use a connection pool (pretty much standard in any web application)

Comment: You'll be dead in the water without a connection pool.